# Using OutputStream with multiple ObjectOutputStreams?

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

To abstract from a specific serialization format I thought to define the following:

```
public interface TransportCodec {
  void write(OutputStream out, Object obj) throws IOException;      
  Object read(InputStream in) throws IOException;
}
```

A default implementation would use just Java object serialization like this:

```
public void write(OutputStream out, Object obj) throws IOException {
  ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
  oout.writeObject(obj);
  oout.flush();
}
```

Obviously the `oout.close()` is missing, but for a reason: I want to be able write several objects into the same stream with independent calls to `write`. Looking at the source code of `ObjectOutputStream` (jdk 1.8), `oout.close()` closes the underlying stream, but also clears data structures that are part of `ObjectOutputStream`. But since I leave `oout` right to the garbage collector, I would not expect problems from not closing the stream.

Apart from the risk that a future JDK really needs the `oout.close()`, two questions:

1. What do I loose in the current JDK when not closing the `ObjectOutputStream` above.
2. First serializing into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then copying the bytes to `out` would allow to close `oout`. Are there better options?

Answer (score 0):

Separate into two interfaces and make the implementation class "own" the underlying stream.

Advantages:

- Underlying storage is no longer restricted to be an [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) / [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).
- By making the two interfaces extend [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), they can now be used in a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.
- Caller only need to carry one reference (e.g. `TransportEncoder`), and will no longer have to carry the stream too (e.g. `OutputStream`).

#### Interfaces

```java
public interface TransportEncoder extends Closeable {
    void write(Object obj) throws IOException;
}
public interface TransportDecoder extends Closeable {
    Object read() throws IOException;
}
```

#### ObjectStream implementations

```java
public final class ObjectStreamEncoder implements TransportEncoder {
    private final ObjectOutputStream stream;
    public ObjectStreamEncoder(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        this.stream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(Object obj) throws IOException {
        this.stream.writeObject(obj);
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.stream.close();
    }
}
public final class ObjectStreamDecoder implements TransportDecoder {
    private final ObjectInputStream stream;
    public ObjectStreamDecoder(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        this.stream = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    }
    @Override
    public Object read() throws IOException {
        try {
            return this.stream.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new NoClassDefFoundError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.stream.close();
    }
}
```